# Query strings and text case

Tags: c#, query-string, case-sensitive

Is it safe for me to evaluate a query string's string and take case (upper/lower) into consideration? Do some browsers lower the whole string for example? Is it reliable enough to code as though whatever parameters I add onto the query strings to remain the same case-wise? (Obviously putting to one side the fact that users might mess with it).

Tagged with C# as I'm not sure if the platform evaluating the query string affects the answer to this question; and it's C# I'm coding in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convention is key.  If you use camel-cased query strings throughout your app, use camel-case, etc.  You're going to be the one passing arguments and specifying query strings, so keep it consistent to make life easy on yourself. Other than keeping it consistent, there's no real benefit to a particular casing convention.

The browser will keep capitalization in tact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I agree, and in keeping things consistent - my query string would include capitalization. My question, however, was regarding the reliability of such case variation. Are there any browsers/particular scenarios that would affect the case I choose? +1.

Comment: The browser will keep capitalization in tact as you pass it in the query string.  Beware of how you're handling your strings prior to appending them to your url to avoid getting your parameters' case sideways.